Apply Where Clause conditionally only when column exists
I want to include a filter through the where clause on a if the column exists in the table, otherwise I don't want to include the where clause. I have provided the entire script below.
This script works when the table has the column (Scenario 1). However, I keep getting an error as shown below when I run this script when the table does not have the column (Scenario 2)
I believe it is SQL Server 2022 Enterprise edition.

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'IsValid'

Kindly help me how to fix this.
/*
Scenario 1 - source table, has column IsValid
*/

DROP TABLE [dbo].[TblDemo];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDemo]
(
    [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsValid] [bit] NULL
);

IF (SELECT ISNULL(COL_LENGTH('dbo.TblDemo', 'IsValid'), 0)) <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Inside If';

    SELECT TOP 50 * 
    FROM [dbo].[TblDemo] 
    WHERE [IsValid] = 0;  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
    PRINT 'Inside Else';

    SELECT TOP 100 * 
    FROM [dbo].[TblDemo];  
END

/*
Scenario 2 - target table, column absent
*/

DROP TABLE [dbo].[TblDemo];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDemo]
(
    [UID] [int] NOT NULL
);

IF (SELECT ISNULL(COL_LENGTH('dbo.TblDemo', 'IsValid'), 0)) <> 0
BEGIN  
    PRINT 'Inside If';

    SELECT TOP 50 * 
    FROM [dbo].[TblDemo] 
    WHERE [IsValid] = 0;  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
    PRINT 'Inside Else';

    SELECT TOP 100 * 
    FROM [dbo].[TblDemo];  
END;


Some things are validated during compilation, for example columns of existing tables, so this won't work. You can wrap the SELECT top 50 * FROM [dbo].[TblDemo] WHERE [IsValid] = 0; in a dynamic sql call to avoid that, since then it will only be compiled inside the IF which is OK.

The simplest and clearest way is to only compile the statement referencing the column that may or may not exist if it exists. You can do that by pushing it down to a lower scope and EXEC-ing it (or using sys.sp_executesql if there is a need to pass parameter values to it).
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.TblDemo', 'IsValid') > 0
BEGIN  
   PRINT 'Inside If';
   EXEC ('SELECT top 50 * FROM [dbo].[TblDemo] WHERE [IsValid] = 0;');
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
   PRINT 'Inside Else';
   SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[TblDemo];  
END

There is another way though which is to provide a column of that name in the query itself to act as a fallback column (DB Fiddle)
In the below the WHERE  IsValid = 0 will be resolved against a column of that name in the table if one exists or the dummy one defined in the VALUES clause otherwise.
SELECT TOP (IIF(COL_LENGTH('dbo.TblDemo', 'IsValid') IS NULL, 100, 50)) CA.*
FROM   (VALUES(0)) V(IsValid)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   [dbo].[TblDemo]
                    WHERE  IsValid = 0) CA 
ORDER BY [UID]

